# What is an order_key in WooCommerce, and how is it different from the id?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

When I'm looking at a WC_Order object, I can see that it has both an `id` as well as an `order_key`. I have tried to find out what the `order_key` is, but there is almost no documentation about it that I can find. Could anyone explain what it is?

I would also like to know why both that and the `id` exists. Is it better to use one over the other in some cases?

Comment: `order_id` was probably set for private class use and not necessarily to be used by developers. `id` and `order_id` are most likely the same number. You shouldn't have to choose. You should use `$order->get_id()`, where `$order` is an instance of the WC_Order Class object.

Comment: order_key is unique key when you place an order. Helps with payment methods , tracking orders, gtags, social tags etc.